# How can you security-harden a Python program?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, security, restriction, seccomp

### What is best way to restrict/sandbox a Python program?

How can I restrict a Python program to *only* be able to access one website and print to `stdout`?

I am using `pyseccomp` to restrict the list of syscalls the program can make, but am finding very little documentation online and had to whitelist 32 syscalls to make the program work (including unrestricted `write()` and `openat()` restricted to readonly (but I'm not aware of a way to restrict it to specific paths).

Is `seccomp` the right tool for this purpose?  I.e. is it the most secure with the limitation of small overhead (e.g. can't add several seconds, hundreds of MBs of RAM, or libraries that cannot be installed with pip3). Is there a better tool that allows Python to read libraries only, but not other files?

---

My program uses [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) to parse a table from a website, I then have a function that sanitizes the data (filters out any entries that don't match a RegEx using `re.match(...)`) before printing it to `stdout`. It will always run on Linux.

Comment: You could run the program as a user that only has the narrow permissions that you require.

Comment: You might run it in a container.

Comment: Is your question how to *install* seccomp or how to *use* it? If the latter, we should assume that you are able to install it.

Comment: "What other methods" is probably too broad for SO?

Comment: @mkrieger1: I have `libseccomp` installed, but when I follow the instructions in the [seccomp source on GitHub](https://github.com/seccomp/libseccomp/blob/main/src/python/seccomp.pyx), I receive a `ModuleNotFoundError`

Answer (score 2):

you try to install this module

```
pip install pyseccomp
import pyseccomp
```

Comment: Thank you! That works just like the [seccomp GitHub example](https://github.com/seccomp/libseccomp/blob/main/src/python/seccomp.pyx). I still want to know if this is the right tool for the job: I needed to whitelist 32 syscalls to make the program work, so that shakes my confidence.